# Having a problem with code that would print the highest number

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write a code that will print the highest number and this what I wrote:

```
a=int(input())
b=int(input())
c=int(input())
if a>b:
    if a>c:
        print(a)
elif a>c:
    if a>b:
        print(a)
elif b>a:
    if b>c:
        print(b)
elif b>c:
    if b>a:
        print(b)
elif c>a:
    if c>b:
        print(c)
elif c>b:
    if c>a:
        print(c)
```

but for some reason sometimes it just doest print anything and I have no idea why. Also the code can't contain `min`, `max`, `and` and `or`. What am I missing?(Sorry for this absolutely awful english btw)

Comment: Did you mean: `print(max([a,b,c]))`?

Comment: How can `a>b` in the first `else`?

Comment: yeah, but i must write the code without using `max` `min` or `and` and `or`

Comment: If `a` is greater than `b`, *none* of the `elif` clauses execute, no matter what the relationship between `a` and `c` is.

Comment: Try without the elif, just use if. The elif makes it so that only one statement will execute. Unfortunately, I believe that means its impossible to get to the c> statements if a!=b

Comment: Also, as others have noticed, there's problems here if the numbers are equal. Consider a=3, b=3, c=2. Even if the current elif problems are fixed, that input won't reach a print statment.

Comment: yeah, this is what i've been looking for! I think I got it now. thank you @user2357112

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand there are much more better way to solve this problem, but I see you as beginner with python, let me try to explain the bad conditional check you are doing here.
The problem with above code is inner and outer conditions with elif/if and if.

> (there can be many such scenario with different input but
> conceptually answer is the same.)

let's say you provided input,

```
4
5
1
```

The logical flow goes like this,

```
a=int(input()) # 4
b=int(input()) # 5 
c=int(input()) # 1
```

Now this condition will failed and cursor will move to next condition.

```
 if a>b: 4 > 5 ( condition false return to next elif)
   if a>c:
     print(a)
```

This condition will be true and cursor reaches to inner if, which will return false and cursor come out of the condition statement **printing nothing.**

```
   elif a>c:  5 > 1 true
        if a>b: 4 > 5 (come out of all the conditional check)
            print(a)
    elif b>a:
        if b>c:
            print(b)
    elif b>c:
        if b>a:
            print(b)
    elif c>a:
        if c>b:
            print(c)
    elif c>b:
        if c>a:
            print(c)
```

Comment: This really helped me to understand, thank you for such detailed response!

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to find out what is happening when nothing is printed it might be useful to add an else statement that would be triggered whenever your other cases don't match.

```python
else:
    raise Exception(f"Case that isn't handled: a={a}, b={b}, c={c}")
```

You can also replace the Exception with a print.

Answer (score 0):

Construct a value that is lower than any possible input value. Compare all input values and assign accordingly.

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())

hi = float('-inf')

for v in a, b, c:
    if v >= hi:
        hi = v

print(hi)
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to do this.

```
myList = [a, b, c]
print(max(myList))
```

Or if you must do it using the greater than operator:

```
if a > b and a > c:
    print(a)
elif b > a and b > c:
    print(b)
else:
    print(c)
```

Answer (score -1):

First off, repeated `if`/`elif` is really cumbersome, and many of your statements are redundant. You could simply use the builtin `max` function, like this:

```
print(max(a, b, c))
```

If you really want to stick to this for some reason, you need to consider the cases where two values are identical. If `a==b`, for example, your code won't return anything. That means:

```
if a >= b:
    if a >= c:
        print(a)
    else:
        print(c)
else:
    if b >= c:
        print(b)
    else:
        print(c)
```